# How to capture a screenshot without my own character in the picture?

Tags: battlefield-4

**Normal screenshot.**

[image: Normal screenshot.]

**Without player character.** (For example, I didn't own this image)

[image: Awesome screenshot.]

[I](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10151928012667672.1073741839.308775617671&type=3) [love](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10151865052197672.1073741837.308775617671&type=3) [these](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10151850064937672.1073741835.308775617671&type=3) [screenshot](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10151850077142672.1073741836.308775617671&type=3). How can I capture screenshot like those picture?

Comment: Can you switch to holding a knife? AFAIR once you've done the first 'stab' motion then the hand holding the knife moves out of shot. Then you can take the screenshot. (I'm not 100% sure on this though, hence a comment not an actual answer).

Comment: What is that pink dress the sniper is wearing? must have!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would assume that they join the server as a spectator, then use the console command `ui.drawenable 0` command that removes the UI/spectator overlay. It's `ui.drawenable 1` to turn it back on.